# Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials: How do I get the Connect wizard to work on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10, essentials-2012-r2

I'm setting up some brand new Dell laptops that have come with Windows 10 Pro preinstalled. I need to connect them to a server that is running Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials.

From what I can make out online, Windows 10 has been supported since about November 2015 and I should just proceed as normal, by pointing the client's browser to http://server-address/connect

The connector wizard loads and asks me for my username and password, then after a bit of a delay says

> An unexpected error has occurred

Right, very helpful, thanks Microsoft ;-)

I've spent maybe a couple of hours googling and found a lot of out-of-date stuff about manually installing the connector; I think that advice is obsolete now.

What's the knack to getting this to work?

Comment: Are the Windows laptops actually updated to 1511?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I've just checked and yes, they are on Windows 10 version 1511 build 10586.63